# simple algorithm to go thru all lexicographic permutaions

Tags: algorithms

I'm working thru the [euler question 24](https://projecteuler.net/problem=24) (not looking for the answer) and came across [this site](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lexicographic-permutations-of-string/) describing an algorithm to get all the permutaions. Here are the steps they lay out :

> Steps to generate the next higher permutation:
>
> - 1. Take the previously printed permutation and find the rightmost character in it, which is smaller than its next character. Let us call
>      this character as ‘first character’.
> - 2. Now find the ceiling of the ‘first character’. Ceiling is the smallest character on right of ‘first character’, which is greater
>      than ‘first character’. Let us call the ceil character as ‘second
>      character’.
> - 3. Swap the two characters found in above 2 steps.
> - 4. Sort the substring (in non-decreasing order) after the original index of ‘first character’.

He says that the first permutation will always be the sorted string, so start with :

> A B C D E F (p1)

first char will be 'E', rightmost char with a greater char following. Ceiling will be 'F', as it's greater than the first char. new string is

> A B C D F E (p2)

we can't sort after index 4 (following 'F', only one letter), so it's good there.

Next iteration, first char is D, ceiling is E, so they are swapped

> A B C E F D (p3)

we sort after index 3 and get

> A B C E D F (p4)

now, our first char is D and ceiling F, we swap

> A B C E F D (p5)

but this gives us a dupe with p3.

Have I understood the algorithm incorrectly? (obviously :)) Also, in the instructions, they don't explain how to sort the original list, the example is in the middle somewhere.

thanks for any help!
bp

Comment: One don't output a permutation before sorting (4), so $p4$ is the 3rd and $p5$ is the 4th.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin : thanks, that was it! I did all permutations of 0,1,2,3 and came up with 24 permutations, where I did not count the unsorted list

Comment: Step 5 is missing: print the permutation